# QsciScintilla marker background color

Tags: qt4, pyqt4

How to set a marker's background color (SC_MARK_BACKGROUND) within a QsciScintilla instance?

I cannot see any way to pass it to markerDefine().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I was missing setMarkerBackgroundColor()